# Get custom message out of the custom exception thrown

Tags: post, http-status-code-404, dropwizard

I am writing a test for a post method for one of my resources

```
@POST
@Path("/api")
@Timed
@UnitOfWork
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

public Person createPerson(Person p, @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
      //do something here or throw 400 exception
```

}

Here is the test

```
@Test
public void testThrows400() throws Exception {

thrown.expect(400Exception.class);
Response response = resources.client().target("/api").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(Entity.entity(person, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE));
assertEquals(response.getStatus(), 400);
assertEquals(response.getStatusInfo(), Status.BAD_REQUEST);

}
```

This is working as expected. But is there a way I can return the custom message I send when an exception is thrown?

Here is the exception class

```
public class InvalidNameException  extends WebApplicationException
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public InvalidNameException(URI location)
    {
        this(location, null);
    }
    public InvalidNameException(URI location, Object entity) {
         super(Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).location(location).entity("Invalid name, please use a valid name").build());
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a similar code block and the response sent will have HTTP status 400 along with your custom message.

Firstly, add a constructor which takes your message as input.

```
public InvalidNameException(String message) {
    super(message);
}
```

---

```
if (invalidName) throw new InvalidNameException("My custom message goes here");
```

In addition to this, use the ExceptionMapper.

```
public class InvalidNameMapper implements ExceptionMapper<InvalidNameException> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(InvalidNameException e) {
        return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(e.getMessage()).build();
    }
}
```

You will need to register your InvalidNameMapper with the framework.
In case of Dropwizard, you can do this as follows in your run() method of your application class.

```
environment.jersey().register(InvalidNameMapper.class);
```